# Confusion on the proof of Zariski and Samuel's Commutative Algebra, Theorem 24 in Chapter 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I got stuck on the proof of  Zariski and Samuel's *Commutative Algebra*, Theorem 24 in Chapter 4.
The theorem says: (I modified the expression, expanding some terms)

> Let $R$ be a noetherian ring.
> $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal admitting an irredundant primary decomposition
> $\mathfrak{a}=\cap_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{q}_i$ with $\mathfrak{p}_i\equiv \sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_i}$
> s.t. all $\mathfrak{q}_i$ are imbedded
> (that is, $\mathfrak{p}_i\not\subseteq \mathfrak{p}_j$ when $i\ne j$).
> Let $M$ be the multiplicative subset $M=R-\cup_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{p}_i$.
> Then $M^{-1}R/\mathfrak{a}^e$, where the extension is taken wrt $\pi:R\to M^{-1}R$,
> has a (finite) composition series when viewed as an $R$-module.

The author proved the fact by arguing that $M^{-1}R/\mathfrak{a}^e$ is an artinian ring,
and therefore has a composition series if viewed as a module over itself.
Then the author says
the statement follows from the fact that
a subset of $M^{-1}R/\mathfrak{a}^e$ is an ideal iff it is an $R$-submodule.
But how to prove that fact?
An ideal is an $R$-submodule is easy, since
\begin{equation*}
r(\frac{x}{m}+\mathfrak{a}^e)=(\frac{r}{1}+\mathfrak{a}^e)(\frac{x}{m}+\mathfrak{a}^e).
\end{equation*}
But why an $R$-submodule is an ideal?

Comment: What if $R=\mathbb Z$ and $\mathfrak a=(0)$?

Comment: @user26857 Yes, this is a counterexample. Thus it seems that the theorem is wrong(? ) For then the theorem states that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a noetherian and artinian $\mathbb{Z}$ module, which is not true : $\{2^n\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a descending chain.

Comment: It might be, although I haven't thought about it, that it should be an $R_M$-submodule, not $R$-submodule.